# Making my game independent from graphic API in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I would like to make my game independant from the underlying graphic API used (in order to reduce coupling in case I want to port it to another platform).

I'm currently using SDL, and initially I wanted to encapsulate the SDL_Renderer in a GraphicAPI_SDL class, implementing my generic GraphicAPI interface. This API would have create Image_SDL (encapsulating an SDL_Texture), which implements my generic Image interface.

My problem is that, when I want to render an Image using my GraphicAPI instance, the underlying GraphicAPI_SDL has to cast the Image into an Image_SDL, in order to obtain the SDL_Texture. And such a cast is ugly.

What is the best way to deal with that type of situation ? I've though about storing every SDL_Texture loaded in a vector inside my GraphicAPI_SDL, with every instance of Image having just an integer corresponding to the index of the texture in the vector, so that only the GraphicAPI_SDL class uses SDL directly, but is there a better way to proceed (with a pattern for instance) ?

Comment: Yes, they are ugly, but such casts are generally how things are done. You should create abstractions that make sense in the context of your game rather than speculatively create a graphics engine. You don't even have to introduce abstract classes, if you keep it clean and don't mix concerns too much, you'll be able to port later when you know exactly what you're targeting.

Comment: Have you considered the PIMPL idiom instead of straight derivation? Another concern, more serious I think, is to look ahead to your next platform candidates and gauge their capabilities compared to the one you currently use, and then create appropriate adapter implementations, so you end up working with platform-agnostic class, that delegates to the current platform adapter via PIMPL. The tradeoff as always is some extra execution time (call the generic method that then delegates to the adapter that finally uses the intrinsic).

Comment: SDL is already cross-platform, isn't it enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SDL 2.0 (and are just making a 2D game) then you are already decoupled from the underlying Graphics API to a large extent. SDL 2.0 can automatically select the correct renderer (DirectX or OpenGL) for your system when you set up the window, your code shouldn't need to worry about it at all. However, if your game requires a lower level of drawing control (i.e, you're making a 3D game), you will need to handle the renderer by yourself.

For more information, see here: http://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide#Video

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/), it has a simple but good architecture that meets your criteria in portability. Basic patterns are [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), the [mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) and the [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). The key to this portability is good interface. We need abstract classes for the `GraphicsApi`, `MeshRenderer` and the `Texture`, and its implementations for all graphics APIs.

For DirectX9:

- `GraphicsApiDX9` implements `GraphicsApi`
- `MeshRendererDX9` implements `MeshRenderer`
- `TextureDX9` implements `Texture`

For OpenGL:

- `GraphicsApiGL` implements `GraphicsApi`
- `MeshRendererGL` implements `MeshRenderer`
- `TextureGL` implements `Texture`

And so on. `GraphicsApiDX9` creates `TextureDX9` that keeps an internal pointers to `IDirect3DTexture9`, and the `IDirect3DDevice9` which created the texture. You're using the created one trough `Texture` interface so you don't care how it is created.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no such thing as platform independence. On every platform, you are forced to make some assumptions that may or may not be true on your next platform. And in any abstract platform, you will be making some assumptions (like the platform supports textures, matrix transformations, quaternions, no 3D support etc). All that an abstract platform will do in create unnecessary complexity.

And abstract platform only starts to make sense when you are considering supporting 2 or more platforms at which point you can abstract away common concepts (like textures and matrix transformations).

So unless you are planning to support multiple platforms, the best you can do is to just ensure that your application is properly layered.

SDL and OpenGL ES are supported on a large number of platforms and unless you are planning to port games to specialist game consoles, SDL and OpenGL ES covers most bases.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (snippets cut as is from my hobby-hack-2d-game-engine) to this looks like this. I start with a handle for any kind of texture (this is graphics library independent):

```
struct MGTexHandle
{
    MGTexHandle();
    ~MGTexHandle();
    void* tex;
};
```

Then, in my graphics library interface class i keep a generic interface of all methods without library specific types. The implementation will have to be ported to each graphics library (and the only one i have tested is SDL2).

For example, loading an image to a graphics library independent texture object (texHandle parameter):

```
void* MGWindow::loadBMPImage(std::string fileName, bool transparent) 
{
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* optimizedImage = NULL;
    loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(fileName.c_str());
    if(loadedImage != NULL)
    {
        if(transparent)
        {
            // TODO: Make it possible to have other color codes than
            // zero represent transparency
            SDL_SetColorKey(loadedImage, SDL_TRUE, 0);
        }
        optimizedImage = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_Renderer, loadedImage);
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    }
    return (void*)optimizedImage;
}

void MGWindow::loadBMPImage(std::string fileName, MGTexHandle &texHandle, bool transparent)
{
    if(texHandle.tex)
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(static_cast<SDL_Texture*>(texHandle.tex));
    }
    texHandle.tex = loadBMPImage(fileName, transparent);
}
```

Rendering a texture onto the screen looks like:

```
void MGWindow::drawSprite(const MGTexHandle &imageTexture, int srcX, int srcY, int dstX, int dstY, int width, int height)
{
    increaseDrawnSpritesCounter();
    SDL_Rect srcRect;
    srcRect.x = srcX;
    srcRect.y = srcY;
    srcRect.w = width;
    srcRect.h = height;
    SDL_Rect dstRect;
    dstRect.x = dstX;
    dstRect.y = dstY;
    dstRect.w = width;
    dstRect.h = height;
    SDL_RenderCopy(m_Renderer, static_cast<SDL_Texture*>(imageTexture.tex), &srcRect, &dstRect);
}
```

The start of the header looks like:

```
class MGWindow : public IMGWindow
{
    private:
        int m_Width;
        int m_Height;
        int m_Bpp;
        bool m_Fullscreen;
        std::string m_Title;
        SDL_Window* m_Screen;
        SDL_Renderer* m_Renderer;
...
```

`IMGWindow` is a pure virtual interface.

I can mock and stub the graphics and execute quite complex automated integration tests involving all components but the library specific graphics routines. And that was the point of the interface rather than being able to port to another library one day, but that should also be quite straight forward now.